# Slideshow position not displaying in JEvents menu item (Joomla 3.4.3)

Tags: joomla, joomla-module, joomla3.4

I am new in Joomla and here is my problem. I set the banner module in slideshow position and assign it in all pages, however when I created a menu item type "[JEvents](https://www.jevents.net/)" ->"View by Month", the banner module are not displaying. Can you help me. Thanks

Comment: Did you try to create other menu items with JEvent component, with different configuration than "View by month" ?

Comment: Yes ,but the result is the same, And also when i created "Category List" in menu item type and set the category i've created containing my article, when I clicked the article title to view the content ,the module banner is not displaying.

Comment: Make sure that the module is set to show on all pages.

Comment: The module doesn't display only in JEvent's menu items ? If not, which other types of menu items have the same problem ?

Comment: No Micheal, It doesnt also displaying in "Category List" menu item only when i click the article title to view the article content ,the module banner disappeared, but i set it  to "show on all pages".